# Pass a .zip file to a Docker container using python

Tags: python, django, docker, stdin

I am using the Docker SDK to try and push a file from a Django web request method of POST to a Docker container. In my use case, the .zip file cannot touch the local machines file directory or load into memory. The file must go straight to the Docker container. This is the code I have so far but I cannot seem to find a way to get a file to passthrough to the container and get back command output from the commands I am running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

# start the container
container = client.containers.run(
    image='myimage:latest',
    command='mkdir /tmp/upload',
    remove=True,
    detach=True,
    network_mode='none',
)

try:
    # write the uploaded file to the container's file system
    container_id = container.id
    container_exec_command = f'cat > /tmp/upload/{zipfile.name}'
    _, stream = container.exec_run(cmd=container_exec_command, stream=True)
    with zipfile as f:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            stream.write(chunk)

    # perform the rest of the processing inside the container
    container_exec_command = f"""
        cd /tmp/upload
        # unzip the file
        echo y | unzip -P {filePassword} {zipfile.name}
        # get the filename of the other file in the directory
        filename=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.zip' -printf "%f\n")
        # run sha256 sum against it, then run file command against it, then zip the file and give it a .zip extension
        sha256sum $filename
        file $filename
        # compress the file with the password "pass1234"
        zip -P pass1234 $filename.zip $filename
        # share the compressed file with the host machine at the original location
        cat $filename.zip
    """
    output = container.exec_run(
        cmd=['sh', '-c', container_exec_command],
        remove=True,
        detach=False,
    )

    # extract the sha256 hash and file command output from the container's output
    output_lines = data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    sha256_hash = output_lines[1].split()[0]
    print(f'sha256: {sha256_hash}')
    file_command_output = '\n'.join(output_lines[2:-2])
    print(f'sha256: {file_command_output}')
    filename = output_lines[-3].strip()
    print(f'sha256: {filename}')
finally:
    container.stop()
```

Comment: What is running in the container?  I'd normally expect it to be unusual to interact with the container filesystem quite so directly, and the long and complex `container.exec_run` commands are scary (I see at least one potentially significant security issue).  Could the container potentially run an HTTP server itself, so that you could make an HTTP POST request into the container (without involving the Docker API at all) and forward the request body in a streaming fashion?

Comment: @DavidMaze the container is just a way to segment the environments so the zip file never interacts with the direct host machine. The zipped file will likely have a malicious file stored inside (for future file analysis), therefor I wanted the docker container to have no network and all my operations with that file to be inside of the container itself until the file is re-compressed with a new password. The docker containers itself has zip, unzip and coreutils but no running services.